# Gemset Like Feature in NVM

Tags: node.js, rvm, nvm

Lets say I have an `angular 2` project which was created and managed with `Angular CLI 1.0.0` and for some reason that Angular CLI has been updated globally to `2.0.0`. This updated packages do everything based on `Angular 4`, which is problem for our older project. So have these global CLI's based on project would help us manage that.

In RVM, you have Gemsets which help you achieve the same goal.

Following article have also tried to explain this pain (https://www.sitepoint.com/solve-global-npm-module-dependency-problem/)

Answer (score 0):

(nvm maintainer here)

This is a feature request, and so is best filed on the git repo.

In this particular case, https://github.com/creationix/nvm/pull/290 already existed when you asked this question, and https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1629 was created a few days afterwards.